# How to get the string, and the string count whole word in the data frame in R (TextMining)

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining

Want to get the string with their counting in r in data frame

The data set is like:

`No Str`

`1 "I like travelling in Australia."`

`2 "I like travelling is America."`

The result should like:

`No Str count`

`1 I 1`

`1 like 1`

`1 to 1`

`1 travelling 1`

`1 in 1`

`1 Australia 1`

`2 I 1`

`2 like 1`

`2 to 1`

`2 travelling 1`

`2 in 1`

`2 America 1`

I have tried to use split the first row and it works but it cannot count the whole word

`strsplit(data[1,2], " "))`

Can anyone help me how to do that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` to get each word in different row and use `count` to count the word frequency in each `No`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result <- data %>% separate_rows(Str, sep = '\\s') %>% count(No, Str)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` from `base R` after splitting the column with `strsplit`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(df1$Str, '\\s+'), df1$No))[2:1])
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No = 1:2, Str = c("I like travelling in Australia.", 
"I like travelling is America.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```